# Linear Stability Analysis of an ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question: Find the equilibrium points of the following ODE and then use Linear Stability analysis to determine the stability. $$\frac{dy}{dt}= cy - \frac{y}{1+y^2}$$**

**My Attempt:**

I have worked out the equilibrium poitns and I believe they are:

$y=0 \ \text{when} \ c=1$

$y= \pm \sqrt{ \frac{1}{c} - 1}$ when $c\gt1$

However I am struggling to do linear analysis for the equilibrium point $y=0$ I am getting zero for the derivative of y when I sub in $c=1$ and $y=0$

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You can look at small $y>0$ and small $y<0$ to study the stability there (basically using the first derivative test instead of the second derivative test). It should not be hard to compute the sign of $dy/dt$ in this situation.

Comment: The question has asked me to use linear stability analysis, therefore I feel that I have made a mistake. Would you be able to identify it please?

Comment: No, you are right that when you differentiate with respect to $y$ at $y=0$ you get zero. That means you need to do something else to figure out the behavior. But that's not that difficult, as you can see by looking at $\frac{dy}{dt}$ for positive and negative $y$ near zero. For instance when $y>0$ you should find that $\frac{dy}{dt}>0$, so perturbations from the equilibrium to the right get amplified, meaning that the equilibrium is unstable to that kind of perturbations. What happens on the left?

Comment: The opposite of the right? Therefore you have an unstable point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something simpler.
The left-hand side is
$$
y(c-1/(1+y^2))=y(c-1+cy^2)/(1+y^2).
$$
So, you only need to look at the sign of $y(c-1+cy^2)$.

The equilibrium points are $y=0$ (for any $c$) and those that solve $y^2=(1/c)-1$, that is, $y=\pm\sqrt{(1/c)-1}$ for $0<c<1$. Therefore:

- for $c\not\in(0,1)$ the only equilibrium point is $0$, and it is unstable;
- for $c\in(0,1)$ we have $3$ equilibrium points, with $0$ stable and the other two unstable.

Comment: Right. --------

Comment: Is that a yes or no? Sorry?

Comment: It is a yes: 3 lines from 0 to 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Linearizing the right hand side wrt $y$ at $y=0$ one obtain the equation for the error:
$$e^\prime = (c - 1)e.$$

Thus, the zero solution is stable for $c <1$.

For $c=1$, the derivative is really zero. The proper conclusion is that any introduced error won't diminish (solution is unstable).